# find a continuous path between two nodes in a grid of XYZ values which fit a certain criteria

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, path, grid

I have an array of XYZ values, in which the X and Y represent coordinates in space and the Z values are a calculated metric based on the respective X and Y.

**I now need to find a path between two given nodes with a known X,Y that falls into a range of certain Z values. This path is often a curvature so I have not been able to use Euclidean distance.** I've read into path finding algorithms a little and believe the solution to this problem is out there.

I've thought that I could maybe use a for loop that starts at the first node of known XY values, and looks out and all directions to see if the Z value in the surrounding nodes satisfies the criteria, and then the algorithm moves to those nodes that do satisfy the criteria and performs the same search until encountering the second known node location. Each node it encounters that satisfies the criteria would be masked so then the output results in a masked array in which the mask represents the path i'm interested in. I have this algorithm in mind but have not found a way to code it.

Does anyone out there have a better way to do this? Or an example code to help get me moving? If you need anymore information or an example data set i'm happy to share but thought the question was basic enough that it wasn't needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are your `X,Y` coordinates regular or irregular? If they are regular, you could narrow your problem scope to `find a path in this 2D array of Z-values`, yes?

Comment: If your `X,Y` coordinates are irregular, you may have difficulty finding/constructing an `O(n^2)` or better algo to find a solution :/

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp they are regular! They are the same width and length and uniform throughout the grid.

Comment: It sounds possibly similar to a minimum-path-length problem (see e.g. [Minimum Cost Path](https://tutorialspoint.dev/data-structure/graph-data-structure/minimum-cost-path-left-right-bottom-moves-allowed)) -- but you say you're looking for a path that falls into a range of values? Does this range always include one of the `min` or `max` possible value? Or is your problem a variant of the "Minimum Cost Problem" where you're searching for "Target Cost Problem"?

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp they have a min and max possible value (including the min and max).